# generator with conditions in python

Tags: python

which is taken from the predefined interval [a=10000, b=99999]
will fill the list (lst) with a random value, taking into account the following principle: on an even index
The sum of the standing digits is equal to the sum of the standing digits on the odd index

Comment: High @LightFury, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems to pick up mid-sentence, as if an earlier part was written but cut off before the question was posted. Can you [edit] to present the question as a coherent whole? If you've tried to solve the problem and have some code, sharing it would help us help you. To learn more about the site, take the [tour] and to learn about how to ask good question, check out [ask].

Comment: yes, I have to write generator from the following interval which takes number like this principle: The sum of the digits in the odd place in this number will be equal to the sum of the digits in the even place in this number

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hit-or-miss generator that works well for numbers in your range:

```
import random

def even_odd_places(n):
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for i,d in enumerate(str(n),start = 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(int(d))
        else:
            odds.append(int(d))
    return evens,odds

def check_condition(n):
    e,o = even_odd_places(n)
    return sum(e) == sum(o)

def rand_nums(a,b,max_tries = 1000):
    tries = 0
    while True:
        tries += 1
        n = random.randint(a,b)
        if check_condition(n):
            tries = 0
            yield n
        else:
            if tries == max_tries:
                return None
```

For example:

```
g = rand_nums(10000, 99999)
s = [next(g) for _ in range(10000)]
print(s[:5])
#typical output: [25641, 45980, 38225, 34320, 94380]
```

Something better than a hit-or-miss approach would require some nontrivial mathematical analysis. There is no easy way to generate all numbers in a given range which satisfy the target condition.